# How can I handle hash keys containing illegal identifier characters in Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

In Template Toolkit, if I have the following variable containing a hashref:

```
[% 
   artist = {
     'life-span' => '1975 to 1987',
   }
%]
```

What is the best way to output the data in 'life-span'?

I have tried...

```
[% artist.life-span %]
```

^This fails because of the hyphen.

```
[% artist.'life-span' %]
```

^This fails because the syntax is incorrect.

```
[% lifespan = 'life-span' %]
[% artist.$lifespan %]
```

^This works, but is impractical in a large app with lots of data.

Is there a better way?

The project I'm working on is a Catalyst based web app and the data comes from a number of different external web services, so I do not control the name of the hash keys. I guess I could pre-process the data in Perl, renaming the problem hash keys before giving it to TT, but that seems like a pretty crappy work-around.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [item](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_item) vmethod: `[% artist.item('life-span') %]`.