# Perl Template Toolkit: Can you access hash keys that have hyphenated names?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

## Perl Template Toolkit

### Accessing Hyphenated Hashtable Keys

#### Question

Can you access hash keys that have hyphenated names?

For example, if you declare the following hashref in Perl:

```
$hashref = {
    'regularKey' => 1,
    'hyphenated-key' => 1,
};
```

And then try to access the entries via the Template Toolkit:

```
1. [% hashref.regularKey %] # Okay
2. [% hashref.hyphenated-key %] # Generates error
```

The error reads:

```
Argument "" isn't numeric in subtraction (-) at myTemplatizedFile line 2.
```

Is there a way to get around the toolkit's assumption that the hyphens are for subtraction?

#### What I Tried

I tried escaping the hyphens with backslashes, but it generates this error when processing the template:

```
error - parse error - myTemplatizedFile line 138: unexpected token (\)
```

#### Backup Plan

I see two options to work around the issue:

1. Change the keys to remove the hyphens.
2. Create another hashref through which to access the hyphenated names, which repackages the names without hyphens. E.g.:

Add in Perl:

```
$intermediateHashref = {
    'unhyphenatedKey' => $hashref->{'hyphenated-key'},
}
```

Change templated file:

```
1. [% hashref.regularKey %] # Okay
2. [% intermediateHashref.unhyphenatedKey %] # Okay
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311303/how-can-i-handle-hash-keys-containing-illegal-identifier-characters-in-template

Comment: Confirmed; that answers my question. Thanks!